# docpad@6.69 install error "node ./cyclic.js"

Tags: docpad

This is the output I see when trying to install docpad.

Error 
ambi@2.2.0 preinstall: `node ./cyclic.js`
spawn ENOENT

Failed at the ambi@2.2.0 preinstall script.
This is most likely a problem with the ambi package,
not with npm itself.

Is this a docpad installer error or an npm error?

Comment: Here is more of the error message.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601

npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "docpad@6.69"

npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Decker

npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33

npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28

npm ERR! syscall spawn

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno ENOENT

Comment: Hi @designerWhoCodes, may you please provide the items requested here under "BUG REPORTS VIA GITHUB'S ISSUE TRACKER" from http://docpad.org/docs/support